# Connection between machines on local network not allowed

Tags: lan

My work has a hotspot with a captive wireless portal. Once I login both my laptop and my desktop, both are connected to the wlan and have internal ip addresses in the same LAN. However, I can't connect from one to the other, and I would really like to remote connect from the desktop to the laptop to use the desktop's screen and input devices on the laptop.

Is there a way around this? Presumably I can ssh out from the laptop to the web, establish a reverse tunnel back to my laptop, and tunnel from the desktop to the web and via the reverse tunnel to the laptop. Unfortunately that ends up being really slow.

Is there some way to connect the two machines directly? Or will the router (wherever it is) simply not allowed any internal traffic?

**[edit]:**

For example, when pinging from the windows laptop to the ubuntu desktop, I get the following (.85 being the Ubuntu desktop, .167 being the Windows laptop):

```
>ping x.x.x.85
Pinging x.x.x.85 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from x.x.x.167: Destination host unreachable
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to know what OS you are dealing with on each computer. Also, your title is misleading for the question you are really asking. Please [edit] it to make it clear.

Comment: Not sure OS is relevant, but laptop is Windows 8 Pro, desktop Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Sounds like the administrator of the network has configured the network to block those ports.  Because there is no reason you shouldn't be able to see your laptop on the network on the destop.

Comment: I cant even ping though... If it is only a port issue, I should be able to configure the Windows laptop to listen on a different one... How would I find out which ports are open?

Comment: Windows by default doesn't respond to ping. You can run nmap from one of the machine to see what ports are open. But be sure that it is allowed, in many places running namp is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure about the captive wireless portals. But if it require the authentication only for the first time you login, then you can use a script to auto authenticate when you log in and then you will be able to do ssh. If not, then what about setting up a http proxy between them and use it. (not sure whether it is allowed by your IT policy)

Comment: Sorry that part might not be relevant or confusing. The captive portal is not the issue as such. I am logged in on both machines, and can ssh out. They just can't talk to each other, which is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. When you authenticate to your portal on both machines, whether ssh works? if not, then I think your router is blocking the internal traffic.

Comment: Yes ssh works...

Comment: Then it is allowed, so the problem is first time authentication right. You can try to script it, like as soon as you login to your ubuntu, it runs a script which do the web based authentication. Same in windows. Then you should be able to ssh.

Comment: No the problem is that even when I can connect to the internet on both machines, they cant connect to each other.

Comment: Then I think the internal traffic is blocked by the router. Not sure how to workaround this. Sorry.

Comment: Yes I believe that is what is happening.